# Using に twice in the [Verb-連用形]に行く sentence pattern

Tags: grammar, particle-に, renyōkei

Consider these example sentences given by my grammar dictionary:

> (1) 私はデパートへ贈り物を買いに行った。
>
> (2) そこへ何をしに行くんですか。

**Observation**: The location is marked by へ instead of に.

Considering that a sentence such as `デパートに行く` is grammatical,

if the locations in (1) and (2) are marked by に, two にs would be present in the same sentence.

**(Question)**: Can the location in (1) and (2) be marked by に? Would two にs cause the sentence to be ungrammatical?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. They can. The two にs are different. The first is location, the other is purpose. The only restriction against using two particles in a single clause in Japanese is for を.