# Causative, causative-passive and particles

Tags: grammar, causation

> 俺一人に琥珀さんと翡翠をかまわせているのも申し訳ないから、とりあえず二人にはもとの仕事に戻ってもらった。

I am pretty sure it's the causative form here since the causative-passive would require 俺一人 to be marked with は.

I am not sure why 俺一人 is marked with に instead of を though.

I understand the meaning of the sentence, it's just that i do not understand why the particles are like that.

Shouldn't it be

> 俺一人**を**琥珀さんと翡翠**に**かまわせているのも申し訳ないから、とりあえず二人にはもとの仕事に戻ってもらった。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

構【かま】う (= "care about", "mind", "worry about") can be used in the forms of both "～**に**構う" (intransitively) and "～**を**構う" (transitively).

For example, you can both say 「俺はお前**に**構っている暇がない」 and 「俺はお前**を**構っている暇がない」, and they're semantically the same! According to [BCCWJ Corpus](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/), "～に構う" is roughly three times more common than "～を構う".

You seem to know how to make causative forms from both intransitive and transitive verbs, but [here's the summary](http://thejapanesepage.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15666#p171340). [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3624/5010) helps, too.

The causative version of "SがVする" is "SをVさせる" if V is an *intransitive* verb that does not take を. So:

> 琥珀さんと翡翠**が** 俺一人**に** かまっている　　(かまう here is *intransitive*)
>   → 琥珀さんと翡翠**を** 俺一人**に** かまわせている (using causative form)
>   → 俺一人**に** 琥珀さんと翡翠**を** かまわせている (swapping word order)

The causative version of "SがOをVする" is "SにOをVさせる" if V is a *transitive* verb. So:

> 琥珀さんと翡翠**が** 俺一人**を** かまっている　　　(かまう here is *transitive*)
>   → 琥珀さんと翡翠**に** 俺一人**を** かまわせている (using causative form)
>   → 俺一人**を** 琥珀さんと翡翠**に** かまわせている (swapping word order)

In conclusion, the original sentence and your suggestion are both valid, and sound equally natural to me.

Comment: perfect.
So transitive verbs have alwasy the を particle and intransitive have the に?

If that is so no wonder I was getting confused.
Looking online I found that 構う is transitive but the example used に.

Comment: I may be wrong but my current understanding is that transitive verbs always take を, and intransitive verbs take various particles (と/に/から/へ and [even を](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21313/5010)).

Comment: Oh ok, I tought you were a native speaker since you seem to know a lot.

Looking up on the internet I found out that it always use  と/に/から/へ  and  を when going from a smaller to a bigger place or when crossing through something.

Comment: I am a native speaker of Japanese, and native speakers of Japanese are generally bad at explaining Japanese using grammatical terms. In fact this was the first time I thought about Japanese causative forms seriously :-)