# Causative Form - Difference between 子供に本を読ませる　and 子供を本を読ませる

Tags: particle-に, particle-を, causation

What is the difference between these two examples?

> 1. 子供**に**本**を**読ませる
> 2. 子供**を**本**を**読ませる

Please give me some other example to illustrate the difference.

Comment: First thing is that you can't have two を like that in the same clause (saves for special cases http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16289/4216).

Comment: In other words, you can't have two arguments with を for the same predicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

子供を本を読ませる is ungrammatical, and you have to say 子供**に**本を読ませる.

Here are the basic rules for causation:

1. For verbs which take を, the agent (or "causee") is marked with に. Such verbs are usually transitive verbs, but [some intransitive verbs take を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21313/5010), too.
2. For verbs which don't take を (i.e., most intransitive verbs), the agent is marked with を.

In your question, 読む is a fairly simple transitive verb which takes an object marked with を. So the agent (子供) must be marked with に.

Other examples:

- **子供を**眠らせた。 I made the kid sleep.
  (眠る is a simple intransitive verb which never takes an object)
- **子供に**歯を磨かせた。 I made the kid brush his teeth.
  (磨く is a simple transitive verb)
- **子供に**磨かせた。 I made the kid brush (it).
  (The object is omitted, but still the agent is marked with に because 磨く is transitive. 子供を磨かせた would mean "I made (someone) brush the kid")
- **子供を**家に帰らせた。 I made the kid return home.
  (帰る is an intransitive verb which takes に, but never takes an object marked with を)
- **子供に**道路を渡らせた。 I made the kid cross the road.
  (渡る is an intransitive verb which does take を)

And you can find some edge cases in this question.

- [When the agent takes を in the causative form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3624/5010)