# Can someone explain how to use the passive here

Tags: translation, passive-voice

Im having a bit of trouble understanding the passive

I would like to translate

"You really want me to say that I'm weak don't you ?"

> 俺は弱いって かなり言われてほしいですね

Is this right?

Another line that I'd like translated is 
"Why do you want x to hate me so much?"

> なんで x で あんまり きらわれて ほしい の

I sure both my translations are wrong

Can someone explain how to use the particles with the passive form ?

Comment: For the top one, (1) I feel like かなり doesn't fit well with the style you're going for.

Comment: One way to translate the first sentence could be: 「お前は本気で俺に自分は弱いと言ってほしいんだろ？｣?Sorry my keyboard's acting up!

Comment: For the second one, it could be: ｢なんでそんなにXから嫌われてほしいの?｣ I think putting the あなたは and 私に or of the same sort in that translated sentence would sound a little unnatural in Japanese.

Comment: Don't mix up *passive form* and *causative form*. There is no passive form at all in your two English sentences, and these can be naturally translated into Japanese without using passive `-れる/-られる` at all. I think what you need to learn here is [how to make a *causative* sentence](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33515/5010).

Comment: ^ Yeah... Try using いってほしい/きらってほしい or いわせたい/きらわせたい...

Comment: I've been speaking this language as my first language for the longest time, and still can't teach people how things work in Japanese. It's a darn shame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I translated sentence 1 as あなたは、本当に私に、私は弱いと言ってほしいの? and sentence 2 as なぜ、あなたはXに私をそんなに嫌ってほしいの?

The phrase "want x to do something" is translated as "Xに～してほしい". If you want to make the phrase passive form, I think it become "～が、Xによってされてほしい(されることを望む)", but it is circumlocutory though.

So, if my translations are correct, I think the passive form of sentence 2 is "なぜ、あなたは、私がXにそんなに嫌われてほしいの?". I don't come up with the passive form of sentence 1.

Answer (score 1):

"You really want me to say that I'm weak don't you ?" translates to （あなたは）本当は私に弱いと言われたい…のだろう？ / …んだよね？ using passive voice.

If you don't stick to passive, "Why do you want x to hate me so much?" can be なぜ（あなたは）そんなにXに私を嫌わせたいの？, as some users comment. If you stick to it, you can't avoid wordy expressions as Yuuichi Tam's example shows.