# Why is 会わせてあげる being used in the sentence:あなたにはお姉さんがいるの。すてきな人で有名人よ。東京へ連れて行って会わせてあげる 。

Tags: causation

I have been practicing in the website japanesetests4you.com and I don't know why 会わせてあげるis being used. I understand that the speaker is saying: You have a sister（あなたにはお姉さんがいるの）. She is an amazing  person and a celebrity（素敵な人で有名人よ）. But what I don't understand is the last bit: 東京へ連れて行って会わせてあげる. Can somebody explain me if it is using the causative form of the verb 会う and why?
手伝ってください．文の意味が分かりません。

Answer (score 3):

会わせてあげる is the causative-form of 会う, followed by the subsidiary verb あげる.

- **会う**: to meet her
- **会わせる**: to let you meet her
- **会わせてあげる**: to let you meet her (for you)

Here, the subject (*I*), the causee (*you*) and the object (*her*) are all omitted because they can be inferred from the context (as well as the use of あげる), but the "full" version is:

> 私**は**あなた**を**彼女**に**会わせてあげる。
>   I'll let you meet her.

The causee is marked with を because 会う is an intransitive verb. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33515/5010) for the rule.

Also note that although it's called "causative", (さ)せる is translated as 'allow', 'let' or 'make' depending on the context. Without the causative-form, 会ってあげる would mean "I'll meet her (for you)", which doesn't make sense here.