# What does "それに意味を持たせるか" mean?

Tags: translation

> それに意味を持たせるかはアナタ次第ということです

I can understand "アナタ次第ということです" as "is up to you."

I'm not sure what the first half means.

nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/63184/motaseru

so "to hold meaning"? Is it "Whatever meaning you find"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rather simple causative form followed by か meaning "whether". (In case you need, you can check the rules of causative forms [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33515/5010).)

- それ**に**意味**を**持た**せる**: "to make it have/hold a meaning"
- それに意味を持たせる**か**: "**whether** you make it have a meaning"
- それに意味を持たせるかはアナタ次第ということです: "(It is that) Whether or not you make it have a meaning is up to you."

That is, the speaker is saying "it" may or may not be a meaningful sign/message/etc.