# Causative verbs: when does the doer take を or に?

Tags: grammar, verbs, causation

父は わたし**に/を** 大学へ行かせました。

I'm confused about what particle I should put after わたし.

When it is correct to put を (and に) after the doer in a sentence with a causative verb?

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): [Causative Form - Difference between 子供に本を読ませる
and 子供を本を読ませる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33510/9831) **OR** [When the agent takes を in the causative form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3624/9831)

Comment: In this case わたし**を**大学へ行かせました is correct.

Comment: If the original verb is transitive it's に, if the original verb is intransitive then it's を

Comment: i know this is a necropost but @naruto if you did put  私に then it would imply that you let your dad go to college right?

Comment: @frei You mean, "I let my dad go to college?" No I don't think so.

Comment: so what does お父さんは私に大学へ行かせました mean

Comment: because i always wonder whether に takes precedence in determining the meaning